# How to install 32-bit libraries of android studio properly to a 64-bit machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-studio, terminal

I have been trying to install Android Studio properly to my  Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit machine, but I can not solve this very problem. Android studio requires us to install some 32 bit files to 64 bit computers. But when I try to install, I cannot solve the problem.

I have given so many inputs to the terminal and couldn't trace them all. However, I'm sure that I wrote lots of commands on installing lib32stdc++6 and other packages that has been suggested on the internet but every time I got the error message:

> [ E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. The following packages have unmet dependencies: X depends Y but it won't be installed ]

Edit: input & output example:

```
***@***:~$ sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-13ubuntu6) but 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 is to be installed
                Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Hmm, `you have held broken packages` makes me think your system was in a non-ideal installation state prior to attempting to install this. Are you in a position to try installing this on a virtual machine (e.g. in VirtualBox) using a clean copy of Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: hey @halfer , actually I solved the problem. (spoiler: it was related with the incompability of 32 bit libraries with 16.04) I'll explain it with an edit in a couple of mins, thank you anyway...

Comment: You should add an answer instead of editing the answer you found into your question. Also please don't add "(SOLVED)" to your title, once you mark an answer as accepted then the question will be solved.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update! I've moved the answer below, so it follows the Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP):*

I solved the problem. I'll write a brief info about the solution process in case anyone else faces with a similar situation. First of all I realised that this problem was all about the incompatibility of 32 bit libraries with 16.04. So that, I changed the "**download from**" section from the **System Settings - Software&Updates**.

Select Netherlands instead of your country's repo, that'll be convenient (mine was Turkey before). Then simply update your repos by typing ***sudo apt-get update*** to terminal. Lastly, install the required libraries for 16.04 by typing **sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6**. After all, install Android Studio from the very beginning. I did all those and now Android Studio runs properly.